# What is this blue area for?

Tags: genshin-impact

I recently re-visited The Chasm to fight the Ruin Serpent, and for some reason I have a blue quest area marked on my map.

[image: Large blue semi-transparent circle]

I have no quests in my quest log, and I do not get any prompts when entering the area.

What does this blue circle represent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This blue circle represents a Lumenspar chunk is in the area.

Once you upgrade the Adjuvant to level 8 it can detect Lumenspar in the vicinity.

[image: Level 8 Adjuvant - Blooming Light's AOE is increased and it can now search for nearby Lumenspar when used.]